# vagrant synced_folder not working after upgrading vagrant to 2.1.1

Tags: macos, vagrant, mount

after having upgraded to vagrant 2.1.1 my vagrant synced folders are not working anymore on a centos/7 guest, osx latest host, telling me:

```
Vagrant was unable to mount VirtualBox shared folders. This is usually
because the filesystem "vboxsf" is not available. This filesystem is
made available via the VirtualBox Guest Additions and kernel module.
Please verify that these guest additions are properly installed in the
guest. This is not a bug in Vagrant and is usually caused by a faulty
Vagrant box. For context, the command attempted was:

mount -t vboxsf -o uid=1000,gid=1000 vagrant /vagrant

The error output from the command was:

/sbin/mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: No such device
```

`$ vagrant plugin list
vagrant-cachier (1.2.1)
vagrant-hostmanager (1.8.8)
vagrant-vbguest (0.15.1)`

`$ vagrant box list
centos/7 (virtualbox, 1803.01)`

`node_config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "virtualbox"`

anybody experiencing the same, and/or has a solution hint for this?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with Vargant 2.0.3 and resolved it by SSHing into the vagrant box and running a sudo yum update -y after the error.  After that a vagrant reload worked.  I eventually made my own version of the virtual box which was already yum updated.

Try

```
$vagrant ssh
```

then

```
$sudo yum update -y
```

then exit machine and

```
$vagrant reload
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have not make symbolic link in share folder. Virtualbox does not allow symlinks on shared folders for security reasons. If you make symbolic link and exit.

Next time you
    `vagrant up`
the error will happen

Answer (score 0):

I have switched to `plugin install vagrant-sshfs`
https://github.com/dustymabe/vagrant-sshfs
which seems to work across different OSes and also deals better with file access rights.